# Rails - Where to put path helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

for this rails app I'm writing there are users, and users have many projects. I've written a helper function to assist in linking to pages.

```
def new _or_edit_user_path( *user )
  if user[0] && user[0].id
    edit_user_path user[0]
  else
    new_user_path
  end
end
```

and

```
def new_or_edit_user_project_path( user, *project )
  if project[0] && project[0].id
    edit_user_project_path user, project[0]
  else
    new_user_project_path(user)
  end
end
```

But now I want to test these and it's becoming clear that rails doesn't want me doing this. What would you recommend?

Comment: Throw these paths into `app/helpers` and include them in any controllers you use them (they'll already be available to your views). Test them by including `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Comment: Thats how I've got it now. Mind elaborating on `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Answer (score 1):

The routing page for rails gives you a better way of linking to [nested resources.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

If you're not too familiar with this method, you can go in the root folder of your project (where you call rails s) and do "rake routes". This will give you the routes it added with this method.

Here's an example of a nested resource:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects
end
```

Comment: I'm doing that. But I want to be able to move conditional logic out of my views. What I'm trying to avoid is a line like this `<% if @user.projects.length == 0 then %>` and then some link to a new project path. And in the else a link to the edit of this first project.